# PHP mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $n=mysql_num_rows($rs);
    $i=0;    
    while($n>0)
        {
            while(($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))&&$i<=5)
                {

                    echo $row['room_name'];
                    $i=$i+1;
                    //echo $n."<br>";
                }
                echo "<br>";
        //echo "n1=".$n;
        $n=$n-5;
        //
        $i=0;
        }

Output:101102103104105106
108109110
```

The row for roomname 107 is missing....
anybody please tell me what is the problem while reentering the loop again...

Comment: An example of the query that you are running might help

Comment: Is this some sort of obfuscated PHP code contest? (I really hope so)

Comment: I notice the output is missing the <br>... I find that disturbing

Comment: The code-syntax police should lock you up son!

Comment: It has nothing to do with your English, this code is just extremely bad. It seems like you've jumped way ahead of your ability level, you're interacting with a database when you're missing fundamentals like for-loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `$i` becomes `6` you fetch a row but do nothing. Because fetching happens before the `$i<=5` check, the fetched row gets skipped.

Change the order of conditions in the `while` loop.

```
while(($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))&&$i<=5)
```

To

```
while($i<=5 && ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up on my comment, this whole chunk of code could have been written much more clearly as follows. (assuming you meant to put in a `<br>` after every 5 records, right now you're doing it after 6 but I think that's probably a mistake)

```
$rownum = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo $row['room_name'];

    if ($rownum % 5 == 0)
        echo '<br>';
    $rownum++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here if are checking  $i<=5 condition so array stats from 0 , so your database values stats from 101,102,..106, so it will 6 elements .

$i<=5 condition remove this condition in while keep the condition if($i%5==0) echo "
"; it will works